# How to set text box value based on multi-select drop down in Info-Path?

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules

I want to set text box value based on my drop down list box selection in my infopath form.If user select value in drop down i want to fill this value into my text box

Comment: What you are looking for are called *cascading dropdowns*. That should get you pretty far combined with the closest search engine.

Comment: I  want to show only selected  value into text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a rule for the multi-selection control to set the value of the text box.

- Click on multi-selection control.
- From the above ribbon > Add rule.
- In the rule select this field changes > set the field value.
- At field select your control that you need to set to set the multi-selection control to it
- At value click on fx > click on insert field / group > click on **show advanced view** and select the Group name of the multi-selection field rather than the value.

Comment: I tried this solution but it showing the last selected value I want to show all the selected values into text box.

Comment: Let me try this in my side , and i will update my answer once it's working

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: Cloud you set as answer now , also check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge :)